# Understanding and fixing a "CommunicationsException: Communications link failure." with HikariCP

Tags: mysql, spring, jdbc, hikaricp

I am facing a `Exception during keep alive check, that means the connection (com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@5d8f3404) must be dead.  CommunicationsException: Communications link failure.` exception and I am not sure how to fix it.

I use Spring Cloud Connector together with HikariCP.

My config is as follows:

```
@Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        int dbcpMaxActive = 10;
        int dbcpMaxWait = 200;
        PoolConfig poolConfig = new PoolConfig(dbcpMaxActive, dbcpMaxWait);
        ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfig("sessionVariables=sql_mode='ANSI';characterEncoding=UTF-8");
        DataSourceConfig serviceConfig = new DataSourceConfig(poolConfig, connectionConfig);
        return connectionFactory().dataSource("CLEARDB_DATABASE", serviceConfig);
    }
```

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
WARN  com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - Exception during keep alive check, that means the connection (com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@5d8f3404) must be dead. 
548563684499435525  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure 
548563684499435532  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1   The last packet successfully received from the server was 429,069 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 19 milliseconds ago. 
548563684499435536  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
548563684499435541  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) 
548563684499435545  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) 
548563684499435548  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) 
548563684499435550  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377) 
548563684499435553  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1036) 
548563684499435556  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3427) 
548563684499435558  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3327) 
548563684499435562  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) 
548563684503629826  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435) 
548563684503629828  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.pingInternal(ConnectionImpl.java:3971) 
548563684503629829  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.ping(ConnectionImpl.java:3951) 
548563684503629830  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.doPingInstead(StatementImpl.java:1509) 
548563684503629831  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1395) 
548563684503629832  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.isConnectionAlive(HikariPool.java:451) 
548563684503629833  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:182) 
548563684503629834  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:108) 
548563684503629836  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) 
548563684503629840  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) 
548563684503629843  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) 
548563684503629844  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171) 
548563684503629846  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450) 
548563684503629849  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
548563684507824128  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
548563684507824130  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
548563684507824132  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
548563684507824134  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:202) 
548563684507824136  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:187) 
548563684507824139  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle.doGetConnection(HibernateJpaDialect.java:385) 
548563684507824141  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:153) 
548563684507824143  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:380) 
548563684507824144  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373) 
548563684507824146  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:463) 
548563684507824148  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276) 
548563684507824150  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) 
548563684507824151  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
548563684507824153  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) 
548563684512018433  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
548563684512018435  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122) 
548563684512018437  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
548563684512018438  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) 
548563684512018440  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
548563684512018442  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) 
548563684512018443  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy143.findAll(Unknown Source) 
548563684512018444  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.bignibou.service.advertisement.impl.AdvertisementServiceImpl.regularDayToTimeSlots(AdvertisementServiceImpl.java:94) 
548563684512018446  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
548563684512018448  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
548563684512018449  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
548563684512018451  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
548563684512018453  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317) 
548563684516212736  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) 
548563684516212741  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) 
548563684516212745  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor$1.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:52) 
548563684516212748  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.invokeOperation(CacheAspectSupport.java:317) 
548563684516212751  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:350) 
548563684516212755  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:299) 
548563684516212758  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61) 
548563684516212763  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) 
548563684516212766  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) 
548563684516212770  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy146.regularDayToTimeSlots(Unknown Source) 
548563684520407054  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at com.bignibou.web.controller.utils.UtilsController.regularDayToTimeSlots(UtilsController.java:66) 
548563684520407057  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
548563684520407061  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
548563684520407064  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
548563684520407068  2015-06-19T14:43:16 2015-06-19T14:43:16Z    82310644    floating-taiga-1576 54.196.30.228   Local7  Info    app/web.1       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
548563684637847575
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [HikariCP FAQ](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/FAQ), it's the second question.